# Error message: 'E:The package mono-runtime needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it.'

Tags: package-management, mono

I run 12.04 and get the following message when I want to update:

```
Could not initialize the package information
An unresolvable problem occurred while initializing the package information.
Please report this bug against the 'update-manager' package and include the following error message:

'E:The package mono-runtime needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it.'
```

Comment: What commands are you running to update?

Comment: Thank you for your question. I simply click on the line "Software Up to Date" which shows up when I click on the symbol in the upper right corner of the screen. I also have a red symbol on top of the screen with the white log inside telling me that there is a system error when I click on it.

Answer (score 0):

You can download the `mono-runtime` installer for Ubuntu 12.04 and install it.

## Ubuntu 12.04 32-bit

Open a terminal by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>, then run the following commands:

```
wget https://launchpadlibrarian.net/200774235/mono-runtime_2.10.8.1-1ubuntu2.3_i386.deb
sudo dpkg -i mono-runtime*.deb
rm mono-runtime*.deb
exit
```

## Ubuntu 12.04 64-bit

Open a terminal by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>, then run the following commands:

```
wget https://launchpadlibrarian.net/200773594/mono-runtime_2.10.8.1-1ubuntu2.3_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i mono-runtime*.deb
rm mono-runtime*.deb
exit
```

Comment: Following your advice, the following appears in the terminal:

Comment: The following appears in the terminal following your advice: papa@papa-laptop:~$ sudo dpkg -i mono-runtime*.deb
[sudo] password for papa: 
(Reading database ... 896130 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to replace mono-runtime 2.10.8.1-1ubuntu2.3 (using mono-runtime_2.10.8.1-1ubuntu2.3_i386.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement mono-runtime ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mono-runtime:
 mono-runtime depends on mono-gac (= 2.10.8.1-1ubuntu2.3); however:
  Version of mono-gac on system is 2.10.8.1-1ubuntu2.2.

Comment: (continued)pkg: error processing mono-runtime (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for man-db ...
Processing triggers for bamfdaemon ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf.index...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 mono-runtime
papa@papa-laptop:~$

Comment: I think the problem is with the installed version of mono-gac: "mono-runtime depends on mono-gac (= 2.10.8.1-1ubuntu2.3); however: Version of mono-gac on system is 2.10.8.1-1ubuntu2.2."  Many thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Since you have 32-bit Ubuntu 12.10, you can find other packages at `https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/precise/i386/package-name` (for example, [https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/precise/i386/mono-gac](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/precise/i386/mono-gac)). You look for the version on the right and click on the top one (for `mono-gac`, that would be [2.10.8.1-1ubuntu2.3](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/precise/i386/mono-gac/2.10.8.1-1ubuntu2.3)). Then, on the next page, download the `.deb` file under `Downloadable files`. Then, do `dpkg -i package-name*.deb` in a terminal.

Comment: To which folder should I download the .deb file ?  I received the following message in the terminal: papa@papa-laptop:~$ sudo dpkg -i mono-gac 2.10.8.1-1ubuntu2.3*.deb
dpkg: error processing mono-gac (--install):
 cannot access archive: No such file or directory
dpkg: error processing 2.10.8.1-1ubuntu2.3*.deb (--install):
 cannot access archive: No such file or directory
Errors were encountered while processing:
 mono-gac
 2.10.8.1-1ubuntu2.3*.deb

Comment: You put `mono-gac 2.10.8.1-1ubuntu2.3*.deb`. That has a space in it. The actual filename has no space in it. This is why `dpkg` can't find the file. You should use `mono-gac*.deb`. The `*` will take care of the part you left out.